# Selecting from a table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select some rows from a table that I have in my database but I keep obtaining null $result. I think the problem is with my sql code.
The query is the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql);
```

The conexion is working fine I have checked so the problem is with $sql. My vareiable $sql is:

```
"SELECT * FROM `invent` WHERE `id_system` IN (500,504,502,498,499)"
```

My table is invent and I have a row named id_system, I have checked all the names and are correctly spelt and the column id_system contains integers and all ones of the query exist in the table.
I keep getting:

```
$result={"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

I don't know why is it not working, it might be because of the spelling in $sql.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand. It might help to provide your full (relevant) script, and sample data in the form of a set of CREATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: I don not think your sql statement is incorrect, since $result contains an empty resultset. It would contain boolean false value if sg were wrong with your sql statement. But you can easily test the sql: paste it into your favourite MySQL manager application (e.g. phpmyadmin) and run it there. Your connectiom may point to a database where the data you are trying to query does not exist, but the table is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but this code might work for you:

```
SELECT 'id_system'
FROM 'invent'
WHERE 'id_system'=500
OR 'id_system'=504
```

And then you could add the rest of the values you need